# Where in ~/.bitcoin are mempool and UTXO pools written?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mempool, utxo-set

Where in `~/.bitcoin` are the two pools in question stored when their size grows above [the size set](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/60608/how-much-memoryram-is-used-by-the-mem-pool-and-utxo-pool) by `dbcache` and `maxmempool` in `bitcoin.conf`.
Is UTXO pool written to such location at Bitcoin Core's shutdown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mempool.dat` stores the obvious, but it it only written there when the node is shut down

`chainstate/` stores the entire UTXO, all the time

Comment: "all the time" = "every time the chainstate cache is flushed", which may be only once per day in current Bitcoin Core version (depending on -dbcache setting).